# OSGi Http Whiteboard pattern

Tags: java, osgi, servlet-filters, websphere-liberty, whiteboard

Moving from web.xml to OSGi Http Whiteboard pattern created bundle-context.xml
how to pass below properties from web.xml in jspServletfilter's osgi:service-properties

```
 <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <el-ignored>true</el-ignored>
        </jsp-property-group>
 </jsp-config>
```

I tried below solution but it does not work.

```
<bean id="jspServlet" class="com.test.servlet.web.servlet.TestJSPServlet"/> 

<osgi:service ref="jspServlet" interface="javax.servlet.Servlet" >
    <osgi:service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.http.whiteboard.filter.name" value="JSPServlet" />
        <entry key="osgi.http.whiteboard.servlet.pattern" value-ref="jspPatternsList"/>
        <entry key="osgi.http.whiteboard.context.select" value="(osgi.http.whiteboard.context.name=cb)" />
        <entry key="servlet.init.el-ignored" value="true" />    
    </osgi:service-properties>
</osgi:service>
```

Comment: which OSGi Http Whiteboard implementation are you using? The felix one?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked one more time, but if I'm not completely wrong the OSGi spec doesn't handle JSPs in a certain way. So what you are trying to do there doesn't work with the Apache Felix implementation.

The only way to have JSPs working with the Http Whiteboard approach is to switch to the [Pax - Web](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web) Project. As it not only supports the Whiteboard approach (spec compliance is still work in progress, 6.0.0-SNAPSHOT) but also more then there is in the spec right now.

To achieve what you want the following is needed with Pax-Web:

```
<!-- JSP handling -->
<service id="jspMapping" interface="org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.JspMapping">
    <bean class="org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.runtime.DefaultJspMapping">
        <property name="urlPatterns">
            <array>
                <value>/jsp</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
</service>
```

an example can also be found in the [samples](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/samples/whiteboard-blueprint/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml) of the pax-web project.

Comment: if questions arise, best to ask at the ops4j mailinglist: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ops4j